# Complicated Logic for Variation of same rhythm C#

Tags: c#

I am working on checking the variation on some integers and filtering it up , so let me say that we start entering integers of 700,768,820,320,790,260,etc... so I want to check if the each integer is within the same rhythm and harmony so 320 will be remove or ignored, 
Let us say the variation must not be less the 75% of the lower number and must not the higher than 75%.

Actually the problem is not checking the new entry if it is higher or lower , but the problem if the rhythm or harmony of the entries suddenly become higher , so lets take an example :

768,799,890,320,380,799,820,1230,1300,1340,1342,1400,680,1340,1280,1490 ,

so in that case I we started in a range of 700 ~ 890 so 320 will be filtered out , and when suddenly the range became between 1230 ~ 1400 so 680 . and we cannot expect what would be the range ,

so how to make a logic that can filter out and put the higher and lower limitations?

no need for any code just I need for logical explanation .

Regards...

Comment: Don't you know the `Max` and `Min` of your stream beforehand ?

Comment: the minimum must be 220 and max is 2250 , but the variation must be on the same rhythm for assembling them .